# How to return output to client side (rest call) from Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IPlugin?

Tags: dynamics-crm

I have created a custom entity and a matching plugin.
The plug-in registers on the Create message of the entity, pre-operation, and synchronous.
Via a rest call the plugin execution is triggered. The input is correct. But I can not get the data out to the client side.

Should I set OutputParameters, change the InputParameter, change plugin registration, ...?
Or should I retrieve the entity afterwards?

*This pattern is described at 
http://crm.davidyack.com/journal/2012/6/26/crm-client-extension-data-access-strategies.html under the command pattern segment*

Answer (score 0):

To update some values in record in Pre-Create you can use something like this:

```
public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)
serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));

Entity yourEntityName= (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"]

if(yourEntityName.Attributes.Contains("SomeAttribute"))
yourEntityName.Attributes["SomeAttribute"] = "SomeValues"
}
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Change `"SomeAttribute"` for attribute name that you want to change and `"SomeValues"` for value that you want to pass into record.

Comment: That was the easy part.
I couldn't get the Output to work.

Thanks to the people at the MS forum I was able to sort this out.
http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1fae5284-1d96-4dae-b25c-27e35a61c636/how-to-return-output-to-client-side-rest-call-from-microsoftxrmsdkiplugin?forum=crmdevelopment

Answer (score 0):

On PreCreate event populate Text area with your results. At the end of Create, your entity will have this field populated with results. In rest call retrieve the entity after it is created and retrieve the results from Text area.

If you are using CRM 2013, instead of using custom entity and Plugin, you can use Actions to carry out server side execution and Actions can be called from REST calls. Actions is like any SDK Message where you can provide inputs and it will have Output.

hth

Thanks
Mak

Comment: I did not know about the Actions. Will have a look at that.